# Running a screensaver on top of console program after inactivity: how to watch for input?

Tags: linux, io

I'm implementing a screensaver system that would wait for user input on a tty, and, in the event that it didn't get any, would play a screensaver until input is received.

How would I *efficiently* tap the user input to the tty (for example `/dev/pts/1`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "If I have two terminals and write cat /proc/<pid of other terminal>/fd/0, I get results that are sketchy at best." I'll say! Why are you doing this? This seems really not the way to solve interprocess communications. But without knowing what you actually want to achieve, it's hard to advise. See [the Wikipedia article on the XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @MarcusMüller the end goal is to have a program that sees (or at least is aware of) every byte sent to either a process's std like `/proc/<pid>/fd/*` or a device like `/dev/pts/1`. I'd very much prefer that this does not require root.

Comment: Let's dig a slight bit deeper! What do you need that *for*? And consoles are completely different beasts than stdin, so, you're raising more questions here, even! Please try to give more applications context. As it's currently written, it really is impossible to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: A screensaving system that would listen in for user input in that process/tty, and, in the event that it doesn't get any, would play a screensaver.

Comment: ah, OK, this is extremely far from what you've asked for :D can you please edit your question to explain this screensaver system, and what it should precisely do? This feels like you need to implement a pseudo-TTY (or use an existing implementation of one), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! So, I assume that screensaver is looking for input to the same TTY that you want to overlay with the screensaver?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is really mostly about PTYs, not std input: key presses in a running process aren't usually standard input!

So, what you need is a pseudo-TTY emulator that will both deal with inputs as well keep a timer for how long nothing has happened on screen.

`tmux` can do that. Install `tmux`, and create a `tmux.conf` in `~/.config/tmux`, containing (at least) the following (60 s screensaver delay)

```
set -g lock-command "the program you want to be screensaver. It has to quit when a key is pressed, but that's your problem to implement"
set -g lock-after-time 60
```

You can then run your "main" program as

```bash
tmux new yourprogram
```

(or just use tmux as usual, see numerous [tmux tutorial](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Getting-Started)s)

Using `reptyr` you can migrate an already program to a `tmux` session; haven't tried whether the inactivity detection still works.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. `tmux` looks fine, no errors or anything, but it doesn't execute `pipes.sh` after 5, 10, or 60 seconds. Also, `tmux` seems to have like a low refresh rate on my virtual console, and flickers every now and then.

Comment: that's unusual!

Comment: Is there an alternative to `tmux`, like something that would connect to a process like `reptyr` and give screensaver support, or would one have to be made?

Comment: I'd first look into what your pipes.sh does. `tmux` is *very* widely used and usually pretty low on bugs. Handling all kinds of PTYs can get very error-prone.

Comment: `pipes.sh` works fine when I run it manually. The same problem arises when I change it to `set -g lock-command "wall message". It just doesn't execute the command.